# How to say "the statistical significance of our result is stronger"?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, bonferroni

I'm doing a Bonferroni correction, after which our result is still significant at the 10% level.

Since my multiple outcomes are highly correlated, for which the Bonferroni is too conservative, I want to say along the line of "the statistical significance of our result is probably stronger / higher than the Bonferroni correction indicates."

However, since a result is either significant or not, it isn't 100% kosher to say it's more or less significant. So how to express the idea above correctly?

Comment: Just say it is significant at *at least* the 10% level.

Comment: "Even worth a conservative Bonferroni correction..." is another option.

Answer (score 1):

Because you claim Bonferroni is too conservative, I suggest using the Holm modification. See:

Holm, S. (1979). A simple sequentially rejective multiple test procedure. Scandinavian Journal of Statistics, 6, 65-70.